# Javascript: Push Object Data into specific index in array and zeroes to rest of the index

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am facing a little issue while inserting object data on specific index in Array.

Here is my JSON

```
let arr = [ 
        {"days":3, "count" : 10 },
    {"days":4, "count" : 12 },
    {"days":7, "count" : 14 },
    {"days":9, "count" : 20 }

]
```

Output, I would like to have.

```
updatedArr = [ 
             {"days":0, "count" : 0 },
             {"days":0, "count" : 0 },
             {"days":3, "count" : 10 },
             {"days":4, "count" : 12 },
             {"days":0, "count" : 0 },
             {"days":6, "count" : 34 },
]
```

so basically I want the object data to be pushed at specific index based on its key called **days**.

If the value of **days** is greater than 5 then it would be a sum of all the **days** value into one and push that at the last index e.g. 5th index.

Here is the code I have tried.

```js
let arr = [{
    "days": 3,
    "count": 10
},
{
    "days": 4,
    "count": 12
},
{
    "days": 7,
    "count": 14
},
{
    "days": 9,
    "count": 20
}

]

for (let index = 0; index < 6; index++) {
const element = arr[index];


let eachObject = {}

eachObject.count = 0


if (element && element !== undefined && element.days && element.days <= 5) {

    eachObject.days = element.days
    eachObject.count = element.count

    arr.splice((element.days - 1), 0, eachObject)

} else if (element && element !== undefined && element.days > 5) {

    eachObject.days = element.days
    eachObject.count += Number.parseInt(element.count)

    arr.splice(4, 0, eachObject)
} else {
    eachObject.days = 0
    eachObject.count = 0
    arr.push(eachObject)
}

}
```

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You could build a new data set with empty counts and update them with the actual values from the array.

Let start with the accumulator.

This is a new array, using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) with a length of `6` items and a mapping of an object with `days` and `count` properties.

[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) takes an array and a *startValue* and returns the changed accumulator for each element.

Inside of the callback, an adjustment for the `days` property is made for greater value.

An update takes place for some properties of the element. Finally the accumulator `r` is returned.

```js
let array = [{ days: 3, count: 10 }, { days: 4, count: 12 }, { days: 7, count: 14 }, { days: 9, count: 20 }],
    maxDays = 6,
    result = array.reduce(
        (r, { days, count }) => {
            days = Math.min(days, maxDays);
            r[days - 1].days = days;
            r[days - 1].count += count;
            return r;
        },
        Array.from({ length: maxDays }, () => ({ days: 0, count: 0 }))
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: can you please explain this solution step by step.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Days would be started from 1 upto 2,3,4,5,5+ so I guess there will be 1  index shifting in array.

Comment: thank you for your answer. sometimes I get errors as **days** undefined even though I get **days** key in data.

Comment: @NinaScholz. it's because of **Array.from({ length: 6 }** . I might get days greater than 6 even sometimes 50 days. so How can I solve this ? Thank You.

Comment: please add some date with more than 6 days and the wanted result from it.

Comment: @XperiaReno, you could use `maxDays` to control the amount of days.